# Renderscript NoClassDefFound During Instrumented Test

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-testing, renderscript

I am writing an Instrumented Test of a class that uses several `android.support.v8.renderscript` functions.

When running normally on a device, the renderscript throws no errors. However when in an `androidTest` I get the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/Allocation;`

The build.gradle defaultConfig:

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 28
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
 }
```

How do I make sure `renderscript` is available during tests?

The project is open source, you can see the function I'm testing, `blur()` where renderscript is used here: [BlurKit](https://github.com/CameraKit/blurkit-android/blob/master/blurkit/src/main/java/com/flurgle/blurkit/BlurKit.java).

Comment: I'm facing the same problem in androidTest. any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

the problem i faced was during the creation of RenderScript object.

> RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);

The error I received was the same as you

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/Allocation;

I solved this by

1. copying `renderscript-v8.jar` from Android SDK dir (Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\renderscript\lib\renderscript-v8.jar) to app module libs dir (ie: app\libs. create libs directory if it doesn't exists)

   Project\

   - app\

     - libs\
       renderscript-v8.jar
2. in app\build.gradle, add `implementation files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')` to dependencies.

`dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ....
    implementation files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')
}`

These didn't work for me

`renderscriptTargetApi 28
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true`